# How to insert line break in Word cross-reference

Tags: microsoft-word-2016, cross-reference, field-codes

I have a cross-reference to heading text with a long heading, and I want to put a line break in the middle to make it more readable.

What I tried: 
- Putting the cursor where I want the break and pressing "Return" doesn't work
- Alt+Return and Control+Return don't work either

Comment: Have you tried shift+return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line breaks in Microsoft Word are done by `shift+enter`.

http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/word-2010-insert-line-break/

Answer (score -1):

I found another way: just start typing text in, and you can hit enter and it will do a normal paragraph break. Then delete the text you typed in. Shift+Enter is faster though. :-)